# Pass Annotation Title to View Controller (swift)

Tags: swift, annotations, segue, title

I'm having a hard time passing the title of a selected annotation to the segued view controller. I feel like it may be something simple that I need to change, but can't figure it out.

Here is the code to prepare the segue:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "viewDetail"){

        let theDestination : DetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
        theDestination.getName = view.annotation.title!
    }
}
```

and here is the code to for when the annotation call out is tapped, it performs the segue

```
   func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView!, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl!) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("viewDetail", sender: self)

}
```

the issue is that, in the prepareForSegue function..it doesn't recognize "view.annotation.title!" stating UIView does not have member "annotation".

I know when I println(view.annotation.title!) in the other function, it works

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `view` in the `sender` parameter of `performSegueWithIdentifier` in the map view delegate method.

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView!, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl!) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("viewDetail", sender: view)
}
```

Afterwards you can read it out of the `sender` parameter in the implementation of `prepareForSegue`.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "viewDetail"){
        let theDestination : DetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
        theDestination.getName = (sender as! MKAnnotationView).annotation!.title!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, I solved it with a simple line:

```
annotation = self.map.selectedAnnotations[0] as! MKAnnotation
```

so that it sends the annotation title of the first selected annotation in the view, which is only one..the one I called.

Comment: where did you put this line? i am trying to do the same thing and can't figure it out